# Polyhedra having equal quadrilateral faces are cubes?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

While discussing with my 11 y.o. daughter about the definition of a cube as regular hexahedron, I observed that actually we can let drop the assumption that the faces are squares, and require only that they are equal.
She agreed, because trying to imagine, let's say, six *equal* parallelograms (without right angles) matching to form a solid leads to impossible solids.

I recently made a conjecture requiring even weaker conditions.

*A polyhedron having equal quadrilateral faces is a regular hexahedron.*

Any hint to prove the statement or a couterexample would be great

Thank you in advance for your attention

Comment: [Rhombic dodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron).

Answer (score 5):

You can "bookcase squash" a cube in two directions, making the faces congruent rhombi, and get a [Rhombohedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombohedron)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note that the quadrilaterals do not have to be rhombuses, either.  The [deltoidal icositetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoidal_icositetrahedron) has 24 identical quadrilateral faces, each of which is a "kite" (two pairs of adjacent edges equal, but not all four edges equal).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the image of the cube under the map $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x+(x+y+z), y + (x  + y + z), z + (x + y + z)$. The faces are all still quads, and all still congruent (by symmetry), but it's not a cube.